# Interchangeability of "such" and "which"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-difference

Can anyone shed some light on the interchangeability of these sentences:

- "... speaking of which"
- .. "speaking of such"

I used to think that they are always equivalent and therefore interchangeable but I haven't seen the latter in a while so I'm not sure about its usage. I'd appreciate some examples.

Comment: Also on [another stackexchange site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/415395/speaking-of-which-vs-speaking-of-such).

Comment: @WeatherVane That wasn't really sufficient so I had to ask it here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example of the first could be

> I received an email about sproggling today, speaking of which, only
>   yesterday sproggling was mentioned in a lecture.

The second usually has a subject, such as this

> I have received a lot of emails about sproggling, mungling and
>   stimming. Speaking of such **matters** would need some research.

Answer (score 6):

**Speaking of which** is used by a speaker to refer to a topic that has just been mentioned either by the speaker or someone else.

It is obviously spoken language and comes at the beginning of a new sentence, or could conceivably be placed in a sentence in a dialogue.

Speaking of such can be used in phrase such as; **Speaking of such matters can be difficult.** But the meaning is not the same as the idiomatic phrase: Speaking of which etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Speaking of which* is relative, like *with which* in

> I have a wok, with which I cook sometimes.

Nowadays you might be more likely to say “that I cook with”, and analogously “that I'm speaking of” (when I say the following).

I've never used *speaking of such*, but it seems to me more defensible structurally as the beginning of a sentence.  It's the same *such* that occurs in the phrase *as such* (when that phrase is not a sloppy substitute for *therefore*):

> I am a member of the club and as such [=as a member] I have access to its facilities.

*Speaking of which* makes syntactic sense (to me) only as a continuation of the preceding sentence, so it shouldn't be used to begin a sentence in formal writing, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score -1):

"Such" is correct and the same, I just always prefer "which".

Comment: No such is most definitely incorrect. And sounds non-native. It is wrong for this context.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say "such" is "most definitely incorrect". It is certainly unusual, and from a non-native speaker it will be noticeably non-native, but I wouldn't bat an eyelid if I heard it from a native speaker. (British English.)

Comment: Patrick: "Speaking of such, shall we really discuss this any further?" It is not standard, and I don't mean prescriptively standard. I get tired hearing about BrE versus AmE. Half the time that fact is totally irrelevant. "Speaking of such matters can be tricky." – Lambie 8 mins ago